# CRSError while when opening shapefile using geopandas

Tags: shapefile, geopandas

I am getting error when opening a shapefile that I downloaded from ArcGIs Hub. I am using the geopandas library in python and the code used is:

```
       data = geopandas.read_file('filepath/name.shp')
```

I get the following error message:

> CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:4326: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: SQLite error on SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name)
> Downloaded shapefile from the following link:
> (https://hub.arcgis.com/search?collection=App%2CMap)

Comment: Please show the content of file `filepath/name.prj`

Comment: File path is accessed via remote server and due to privacy concern cannot disclose. It is the same way other files get opened though. I have added the link from where I downloaded the shapefile of Indian Urban cities. Thanks.

Comment: I did not ask for `filepath`. You can read and share the content of the file `name.prj`. Also the relevant code (not all code) that you use is important for us to investigate for the cause of errors.